# AKS service response is slow after idle time

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-virtual-network

I set up my Azure Kubernetes Service deployment exactly as it's described in the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip) with static IP, Ingress Controller and Let's Encrypt SSL certs. I use:

- Standard_B2s node size
- 1-node pool
- Single pod
- AKS Network type: Basic (Kubenet)
- Let's Encrypt certs for prod

Response latency sometimes is very very high. One browser can very quickly get to the service (open swagger for instance) but then I go to my mobile phone and try to open it from it. It takes forever and often times out. As soon as you open the page once, next time it would most likely open very fast and without any delays. Why does it happen?

I can guarantee, it's not my service issue.

Comment: Could it be an effect caused by the B series? Unsure of how exactly the bursting processing is actually managed by azure.

Comment: @Carson it's not even the smallest and there is 0 load on my service and it's not really doing much. It's just rest API.

Comment: I was more wondering if burst machines tend to deallocate their virtual resources when not in use. If that were the case, it wouldn't matter how small your application was, reallocation of the resources could cause a delay, and then once the vm was processing adequately again, it would be able to serve the application at a high speed. It's just speculation.

Comment: @Carson that was my guess. But I do see slowness if I try to open webpage in incognito window. I'm thinking it's the certificate or domain name resolution. Contacting godaddy now to see if they can help with the dns part..